# ReactiveForms valueChanges in dom vs component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm wonder if there's a way to know the difference whether `valueChanges` on a `FormControl` was triggered from the dom or the component itself. My use case is I need to do `stuff()` when the user changes the value, but I don't want to do `stuff()` if the value changed as a result of something else. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This is an interesting question. Unfortunately I am pretty sure that this kind of API does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Nobady, who inspired the idea. I found there's actually an option for `setValue` on the formControl called `emitEvent`. Using this, I can make it so if I update the value programmatically I can bypass the `valueChanges` getting called.

Answer (score 1):

with the control ".touched"

> EXAMPLE:
>   **YourModelForm**.get('**YourField**').touched

the value becomes true when the user enters a value (first click on the field, enter the value, tab or click out of the field).

I tried with a call rest and the value remains to false, try it if you can possibly it works for your situation. :-)